signal peptides that can keep proteins at ER
I am studying an exogenous protein X that can modify specific mRNA. I would like to maintain the protein X in the rough endoplasmic reticulum. Are there any signal peptides that can maintain the protein on the cytoplasmic side of the rough endoplasmic reticulum?

I'm not an expert so take this with a grain of salt, but I'd suggest looking into the endogenous mechanisms by which proteins get anchored to the ER in the configuration that you like.
For example tail-anchoring by a hydrophobic transmembrane domain appears to be a common means by which cytosolic-side ER localization occurs. You could presumably use such a domain as a signal peptide. You might need to take some care in design, though, to ensure that cells will actually load the protein in question into the ER. That would argue for finding a specific endogenous example of the localization you want to see.
Here is a specific protein example that may be viable when expressed inside the target cell. But you may want to read up more specifically on the localization that you desire, since there are several flavors of ER membrane localization.
I assume that you want to express the protein inside your cells of interest, given that the cotranslational mechanisms for loading proteins into the cytoplasm are elaborate and possibly necessary for your application.
